# How to Increment the minutes value in timer using javaScript

Tags: javascript, timer

For a timer(minutes:seconds)if it has time of 30:00 how to increase the minutes part of it and display it in a input box?

My Html Code is

```
<input name="timer" id="timer" value="30:00" type="text" onclick="incre()"></input>
```

My javascript code is

```
function incre()
{
    var textbox = document.getElementById("timer");
    var time = document.getElementById("timer").value.split(":");
    var minutes = parseInt(time[0]);
    var seconds = parseInt(time[1]);
    minutes = minutes++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are increasing minutes, alright. But you are not updating it in the text field. Also, [read the basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Examples). There's no `</input>`.

- You don't need a `parseInt()` for `0`.
- You don't need to assign `minutes++` to `minutes`.

```js
function incre() {
  var textbox = document.getElementById("timer");
  var time = document.getElementById("timer").value.split(":");
  var minutes = parseInt(time[0]);
  var seconds = (time[1]);
  minutes++;
  document.getElementById("timer").value = minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

```html
<input name="timer" id="timer" value="30:00" type="text" onclick="incre()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function incre() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("timer");
    var time = textbox.value.split(":");
    var minutes = parseInt(time[0]);
    var seconds = parseInt(time[1]);
    minutes++;
    textbox.value = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}
```

Note that `minutes = minutes++` is unnecessary, you just need to do `minutes++`.

With the last line, you update the input's value.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain anything. Can you provide an explanation instead of just blatantly asking the OP to copy and paste?